# Sequelize - Association Many to Many - 3 Foreign Keys

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js, many-to-many, associations

I'm looking for some help on properly defining an association table with 3 foreign keys in a Sequelize model:

**Situation:** I'm building an email client, the relative models to this question are:

- **User** Model (user records)
- **Thread** Model (thread records for each new email-thread)
- **Folder** Model (folders for default folders e.g. inbox, sent, etc and custom folders)
- **ThreadFolder** Model (association linking a specific a) **User** Model, to a specific b) **Thread** Model, to a specific c) **Folder** Model)

**Problem:** My problem is the association model/table (ThreadFolder), I'm not able to create an association for all 3 tables in the ThreadFolder association Model.

---

**First Attempt** I'm able to create an association with Sequelize that allows the ThreadFolder model to create foreign keys for 2 of the three models above, but not all 3. Here is the association for that:

```
Thread.belongsToMany(Folder, { through: ThreadFolder, foreignKey: 'thread_id', otherKey: 'folder_id' })
Folder.belongsToMany(Thread, { through: ThreadFolder, foreignKey: 'folder_id', otherKey: 'thread_id' })
```

**SQL Input Attempts:**

1. user_id: 1 | thread_id: 1 | folder_id: 1 | Successful Insert
2. user_id: 1 | thread_id: 1 | folder_id: 2 | Successful Insert
3. user_id: 1 | thread_id: **2** | folder_id: 1 | Failed Insert -- Error below...
4. user_id: 2 | thread_id: 1 | folder_id: 1 | Successful Insert
5. user_id: 2 | thread_id: 1 | folder_id: 2 | Successful Insert

**First Attempt's Error:**

```
Executing:
INSERT INTO `iwantmail-core`.`thread_folders` (`user_id`, `deleted`, `archived`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `thread_id`, `folder_id`) VALUES ('1', '0', '0', '2020-03-05 23:34:16', '2020-03-05 23:34:16', '30', '1');

Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
ERROR 1062: 1062: Duplicate entry '30-1' for key 'PRIMARY'
SQL Statement:
INSERT INTO `iwantmail-core`.`thread_folders` (`user_id`, `deleted`, `archived`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `thread_id`, `folder_id`) VALUES ('1', '0', '0', '2020-03-05 23:34:16', '2020-03-05 23:34:16', '30', '1')
```

---

**Second Attempt** I can specify the association as shown below, to allow me to add records with different user_id and folder_id, however, if I use a different thread_id, I get an error shown below.

```
Folder.hasMany(ThreadFolder, { foreignKey: 'folder_id' })
ThreadFolder.belongsTo(Folder, { foreignKey: 'folder_id' })
Thread.belongsToMany(Folder, { through: ThreadFolder })

Thread.hasMany(ThreadFolder, { foreignKey: 'thread_id' })
ThreadFolder.belongsTo(Thread, { foreignKey: 'thread_id' })

User.hasMany(ThreadFolder, { foreignKey: 'user_id' })
ThreadFolder.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey: 'user_id' })
Folder.belongsToMany(User, { through: ThreadFolder })
```

**SQL Input Attempts:**

1. user_id: 1 | thread_id: 1 | folder_id: 1 | Successful Insert
2. user_id: 1 | thread_id: 1 | folder_id: 2 | Successful Insert
3. user_id: 1 | thread_id: **2** | folder_id: 1 | Failed Insert -- Error below...
4. user_id: 2 | thread_id: 1 | folder_id: 1 | Successful Insert
5. user_id: 2 | thread_id: 1 | folder_id: 2 | Successful Insert

**Second Attempt's Error**

```
Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
ERROR 1062: 1062: Duplicate entry '1-1' for key 'PRIMARY'
SQL Statement:
INSERT INTO `mail-core`.`thread_folders` (`user_id`, `thread_id`, `folder_id`) VALUES ('1', '2', '1')
```

---

Note that I'm basically trying to indicate that User#1 of Thread#1 are in Folder#1 and as soon as I try to indicate that User#1 of Thread#2 are in Folder#1, the above error occurs.

---

**Help:**

- Could someone please point me towards the right direction / show how the association should be written to take into account the 3rd association?
- Is there a different way to write this association all together so all 3 foreign keys are taken into account in the association table?

Thanks for any help/assistance in advance!

(Relative technologies used: MySQL, MySQL Workbench, Node 12.x, TypeScript, Serverless Framework)

EDIT: Made edits to the post, 2nd attempt was presented as a partial solution, after further testing, both 1st and second attempts fail when a 2nd user is added to the same thread and folder in the association table ThreadFolder.

Comment: Can you please post the create statements generated by Sequelize using `Sequelize.sync({ force: true })`

Comment: @SohamLawar

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `thread_folders` (`user_id` INTEGER, `deleted` TINYINT(1) DEFAULT false, `archived` TINYINT(1) DEFAULT false, `created_at` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updated_at` DATETIME NOT NULL, `thread_id` INTEGER , `folder_id` INTEGER , PRIMARY KEY (`thread_id`, `folder_id`), FOREIGN KEY (`thread_id`) REFERENCES `threads` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, FOREIGN KEY (`folder_id`) REFERENCES `folders` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE) ENGINE=InnoDB;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working solution ended up being a variance of the second attempt:

```
User.hasMany(ThreadFolder, { foreignKey: 'user_id' })
ThreadFolder.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey: 'user_id' })

Folder.hasMany(ThreadFolder, { foreignKey: 'folder_id' })
ThreadFolder.belongsTo(Folder, { foreignKey: 'folder_id' })

Thread.hasMany(ThreadFolder, { foreignKey: 'thread_id' })
ThreadFolder.belongsTo(Thread, { foreignKey: 'thread_id' })
```

Most of my model calls (based on how they were written before) will end up changing to start with the association table first e.g.

```
 ThreadFolder.findAll({
        where: {
            user_id: 1,
            folder_id: 1,
        },
        include: [
            {
                model: Thread,
                include: [
                    'recipient',
                    'sender'
                ]
            }
        ]
    })
```

Hope this helps others that have attempted to do a multi-foreign key association table beyond 2 foreign keys, presumable this approach should work with any amount of foreign keys in the association table.

Answer (score 1):

After looking at your create statements I think you have defined associations `thread_folders` properly. In my opinion, your second attempt at defining association is correct.

You are getting an error while inserting records because your primary key is the combined key of two attributes namely `thread_id` and `folder_id`. Let us say that in your `thread_folders` table there is already record for `thread_id` 1 and `folder_id` 1 then you can not insert another record with `thread_id` 1 and `folder_id` 1.

If you remove the combined primary key of `thread_id` and `folder_id` then you will be able to insert the records that you want to insert in the `thread_folders` table.

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks @Soham, I'm not sure how to primary keys from the association, I've attempted to use primaryKey: false. That said, I indeed took the second route and after more trial and error I found a solution, I'll post it here soon, many thanks!

Comment: @Speros, welcome. Glad to know that you have found a solution.